# Pressing buttons while Web Scraping python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape over http://www.ign.com/ to be able to scrape over their videogame news, but their format has a slider reel where you select what type of news you want. By default this is set to "latest" but I want to be able to activate the "games" button to be able to extract info from there. How would I do this with Beautiful Soup?

Comment: You should look at the Selenium Project, which allows you to control browsers and perform actions. There are Python bindings: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Answer (score 0):

You could use selenium. Here's how to do that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.ign.com/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.all-games').click()
time.sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

You can now parse `soup` to get the "Games" information.